# How to copy a file in a VMware Workstation Linux virtual machine to Windows

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have installed (using VMware Workstation) a Linux virtual machine on my Windows 7 computer.
I'm wondering how to copy a file in Linux to Windows. To copy from Windows to Linux virtual machine is easy; just drag and drop. But the reverse is not obvious to me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to please install Cygwin in your windows PC and you can following command for copy windows to Linux.

scp /cygdrive/d/test.txt  :/root/test.txt

Or you can also use WinSCP, It is very simple.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure, you have **VMWare tools installed** on linux VM.
2. Select the file (want to copy)
3. `Ctrl + C`
4. `Ctrl + V` to paste in your host machine "Windows 7"

Most probably, you **don't have VMWare tools installed** in linux VM

**Reference:**

- [Copy and Pasting](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_running8.html)
- [Sharing Files Between Guest and Host Operating Systems](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_running9.html)